# How do I configure Dropbox to automatically delete the pictures from my phone that have already been uploaded via camera upload?

Tags: dropbox

I use the camera uploader to back up all my photos but i don't want them in my phone after they have been uploaded. I would like to configure Dropbox to automatically delete the pictures that have been uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

It would be great if Dropbox could add auto-delete after upload.

They way that I get around this limitation and still use Dropbox is to:

1. Disable autoupload to Dropbox in preferences
2. Connect your iPhone and launch "Image Capture"
3. In the lower left corner of Image Capture choose "delete after import."
4. Choose your Dropbox Photo folder and after import your phone will be cleared of the images and Dropbox will have your photos.

If Drop Box needs more inspiration they could look at Eye-Fi to see how Endless memory is setup to do the same thing.

Comment: It really is insane that nobody has come up with a way to automatically delete photos from the iphone once they are backed up to icloud or dropbox. When my wife wants to take any pictures on her iPhone 4 we have to switch back and forth between dropbox and camera roll, manually comparing photos one-by-one until she has room to snap a few more. It is a constant job. - posting this as its own question and asking lifehacker.

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible.